# Where can I find a digital copy of 黄继忠's translation of 论语?

Tags: translation, resources

I'm looking for a digital copy of Chichung Huang (黄继忠)'s translation of The Analects of Confucius (论语).

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195112768)'s blurb mentions what they believe are the advantages of the translation:

> Far more literal than any English version still in circulation, this brilliant new rendition of The Analects helps the reader not only to acquire and accurate and lucid understanding of the original text, but also to appreciate the imagery, imagery, parallelism, and concision of its classical style. The translator Chichung Huang, a Chinese scholar born in a family of Confucian teachers and schooled in one of the last village Confucian schools in South China, brings to this treasure of world literature a sure voice that captures the power and subtleties of the original. Vivid, simple, and eminently readable, this illuminating work makes the golden teachings of the sage of the East readily available to anyone in search of them.

Where can I find a digital copy? There aren't any on sale on Amazon. Any djvu, pdf, etc. would be a big help. Ideas?

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.ixueshu.com/h5/document/e9d0c5b740fa8306da2c8edfb4f34cc1318947a18e7f9386.html Seems like you have to register and log in first to download PDF from the site

Comment: @TangHo That looks like a study paper based off the translation rather than the book itself.

Answer (score -1):

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6253.1998.tb00513.x

Please have a try with this link. It seems that we can download the pdf by logging in with an institutional account.

Comment: That's not the translation, that's a book review of the translation.